# Exception occurred after porting the code of the TOM module of the TC367 project to TC389

Tags: embedded, infineon

The dependency files in the project have been modified to TC389 related files. After running the register assignment code, some registers related to the TOM module cannot be assigned values, some can be assigned correct values (such as assigning 2 register values to 2), and some are assigned incorrect values (such as assigning 2 register values to 3). What is the reason for this?

What should I do to ensure that the ported code TOM module can run successfully on TC389